# Google Kubernetes Enginge NAT routing outgoing IP doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nat

I want to connect GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) cluster to MongoDB Atlas. But I need to green the IP of my nodes (allow them). But sometimes I have 3 nodes, sometimes I have 10 and sometimes nodes are falling down and re-creating - constant changing means no single IP.

I have tried to create NAT on the GCP followed this guide: https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-nat-with-gke-cluster-c82364546d9e

Also I want to green my cluster's IP in the Google Maps APIs so I can use the Directions API, for example.

This is a common situation, since there may be many other third party APIs that I want to enable that require incoming requests from certain IPs only, besides Atlas or Google Maps..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "green IP"? And what is the result of following that medium tutorial?

Comment: What issues were you having with Cloud NAT and GKE?  Do you have a GKE public or private cluster?

Comment: I do have a GKE private cluster (I don't sure what you mean by private.. I just have Kubernetes cluster in GCP).

Green IP I mean - allowed IP - like whitelisted. 

And related to the medium tutorial - I just followed it up and all services in the GCP dashboard are status of "Running" but the actual outbound transfer goes from the node's IP instead of the NAT's. I have created a static ip, Cloud NAT, NAT router and it all attached to the same VPC of the GKE. but still now work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private GKE cluster means the nodes do not have public IP addresses but you mentioned

> the actual outbound transfer goes from the node's IP instead of
> the NAT's

Looks like you have a public cluster of GKE, you have to use the same NAT option to get outbound egress **single IP**.

If you are using the **ingress** which means there is a **single point** for incoming request to **cluster** but if your Nodes have **public IP** PODs will use **Node's IP** when there is an outgoing request unless you use **NAT** or so.

Your single outbound IP will be there, so all requests going out of PODs won't have node's IP instead they will use the **NAT** IP.

**how to set up the NAT gateway**

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

Here is terraform ready for the GKE clusters, you just have to run this terraform example bypassing **project ID** and others **vars**.

The above terraform example will create the NAT for you and verify the PODs IP as soon as NAT is set. You mostly won't require any changes in NAT terraform script.

GitHub link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/v1.2.3/examples/gke-nat-gateway

if you dont have idea of terraform you can follow this article to setup the NAT which will stop the SNAT for PODs : https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-clusters-egress-traffic-via-cloud-nat-for-ip-whitelisting-7fdc5656284a

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand none of the described in the Terafom link. Can you walk me through the GCP dashboard instead?

Comment: https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-clusters-egress-traffic-via-cloud-nat-for-ip-whitelisting-7fdc5656284a

Comment: This guide is bad. Instructions are not properly written

Comment: yes you are right just noticed it, i would recommend checking out TF version thn, only two command needs to be run. `terraform init && terraform apply
`

Answer (score 2):

*Private* GKE cluster means the nodes do not have public IP addresses. If the service on the other end is receiving packets from node's own IP then you have a public cluster.
You can find further explanation in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept).
If you want a static, public IP for the entire GKE cluster, you should consider [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb) for External Load Balancing. You can find instructions on how to configure it [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress).

Comment: My nodes are not accessible from outside. I am using a managed LoadBalancer routed with Ingress to handle incoming requests. Does this mean my cluster is private now?

Comment: I see now that in the Private cluster property its configured to "Disabled" and it cannot be changed. Should I create another cluster and configure it to be private?

Comment: Clusters cannot be converted from private to public and vice versa.  You can either start with a new cluster or try solution offered by @Harsh Manvar.