# Kubernetes Pod ipv4 address for outgoing http request

Tags: http, kubernetes, dns, devops

Pod A is on ClusterIP service type, so incoming requests from external resources are not allowed.
Pod A executes outgoing requests to 3rd party services (Such as Google APIs).
And I want to specify the IP address that this request is coming from on google for security reasons.

Is there a way to find the IP address this pod uses for outgoing HTTP requests?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953196/5525824

Answer (score 1):

If it is a public cluster where each node in the cluster has an ip address the  public ip will be the address of the node the pod is on.
If it is a private cluster you can deploy a nat gateway for all the nodes and specify static ip addresses.

you can use this terraform module for a private cluster:
https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/modules/private-cluster

Plus a nat gateway from here
https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#terraform

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for! I greatly appreciate your help!